# What is the 'one of your other posts' of a deleted post?

Tags: support

[This](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/02/mocking-singletons-with-ocmock/) is a post that about mocking singletons with ocmock.

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672231/4845454) was deleted because it was a link-only answer.

I edited it. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/719882/4845454 is similar to mine.)

Then it was deleted by [George Stocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker).

I did some research and found [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) that says:

> If your post was deleted by a moderator, you can flag one of your other posts and write a note in the "other" section explaining the situation and requesting undeletion.

I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37672231/revisions)

I was wondering what is 'one of your other posts'? So I can get my answer undeleted.

Comment: Literally one of your other answers. Don't put too much hope into getting the answer undeleted, though. It's still not very good.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks,I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your other posts are your [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4845454/%e5%ad%99%e5%8d%9a%e5%bc%98?tab=answers) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4845454/%e5%ad%99%e5%8d%9a%e5%bc%98?tab=questions)

Pick any one of those 30 and raise a custom flag against it explaining the situation.

However your deleted post does not explain how to

> create a category on the singleton in your test code that overrides the singleton instantiator

It merely says you should and presumably the link explains how. If you want it undeleted you're probably going to need to explain how to do that in the answer rather than leaving it to the link. Some example code would be nice.

Comment: I pick one of my answers.

When i flagged it,i found that 'I am flagging to report this answer as...

in need of moderator intervention'.

Is it the place that write a note?

Comment: That's right, explain clearly that you've improved it and want it undeleted.

Comment: @孙博弘 And don't forget to put the URL of the answer you're asking about in that flag's comment.

Comment: Of course, I  put the URL of the answer.But for now,I could not watch the flag's comment and could not find a way to provid more information.

Comment: It confuse me,when i found that i have to explain the situation and request undeletion by flag one of my other posts and write a note in the "other" section..I come from China,i thought my interpretation is wrong and it is crazy at that moment.

Comment: @孙博弘 that's the way it's done here, you're not crazy.